# How to fully trust a non-signed assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-assembly, full-trust

I've got an assembly, which works just fine on my own pc, but when I try to reference it on a virtual machine, I'm getting following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'X.dll' or one of its ependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'X.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm,Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at kernelLoader.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I'm absolutely sure that the file is at the location specified, and the code works fine on my own machine (where it has been developed). It, together with all referenced assemblies, are compiled for x86 platform.

I think, that the error may be caused by the assembly not being fully trusted.

I can't strong sing the assembly, because it references several assemblies, which are not singed, and to which I don't have the code or the rights to modify.

I suspect that there is a good way of making an assembly trusted on the mashine where I run it.

How do I mark an assembly as trusted so it can be loaded and executed?

Comment: Check to see if there is a third assembly which is missing upon which 'X.dll' depends. Your app->X.dll->missing.

Comment: I did that with reflector. All assemblies seem to be present. Also, in the exception, X.dll is marked as missing (File name: 'X.dll')

Comment: Copy the file again, it may have been broken when copying.

Comment: Yeah, the exception message can be misleading. Used to see this exception a lot with an older version of NHibernate (when the Castle dependency wasn't forced to be included in build). It can't load X.dll, because it can't find something that X.dll needs... This can also be a case where some .dll isn't in the PATH (something not installed on the VM)... Try using something like Dependency Walker (instead of Reflector) to see if it will sniff something else out... Iirc, it's an invalid operation exception when it comes to no trust, and a bad format when it comes to 32bit vs 64bit.

Comment: @Stefan: I've tried doing that many times already

Comment: @cloggins: I've tried using Dependancy Walker, It's of little use for managed dlls. I've also tried fusion, and it tells me that X.dll is loaded successfully, and that there are no errors at all

Comment: When you say it runs on the dev box, do you mean in the IDE or installed on the dev box?

Comment: I mean, that I can run in when it is on my computer any way I like - through command  prompt or through IDE. I noticed the problem only after I've copied the files to virtual machine

Comment: Only other thing I can think of trying to diagnose would be to use ProcMon and watch for the error. You should be able to see what file it's looking for. I really don't think it's a trust issue (but admit could be wrong). No other ideas, except to double-check all the obvious things (config files/assembly redirects, assembly names, paths, etc.). There may be something very obvious installed on the dev box which is not on the VM. Can you try running it on another dev box?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12116/discussion-between-cloggins-and-arsen-zahray)

Comment: @cloggins: ok. ProcessMon did the trick. the missing dll was msvcr100d.dll. Don't know what this is about, but adding it solved the problem. Could you answer the question with ProcessMon so I can mark it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception is usually caused by a missing dll. One thing that can be used is ProcMon. When the missing dll is loaded and an error is through, the file name should show up in ProcMon.